# Visual studio 2015 professional class diagram with multiple association

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uml, class-diagram

I tried create a class diagram with multiple association no Visual Studio 2015 Professional but no find the property who I have to change.
In the example I saw is in the 'Second Role', but it was Visual Studio Ultimate, the  Professional I not find this property

Comment: The Visual Studio 2015 Professional apparently does not have this feature only the Ultimate version

Comment: Unfortunately this problem is the version of visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2015 Professional apparently does not have this feature only the Ultimate version